# Why does Android's Bundle API accept ArrayLists rather than Lists

Tags: java, android, api-design, android-development

I'm new to Android and while going through a tutorial on saving `Activity` state to a [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html), I noticed that instead of accepting the more generic `List` interface, `Bundle`'s put methods are expecting `ArrayLists`.

Example:

```
Bundle.putCharSequenceArrayList(key, value)
Bundle.putIntegerArrayList(key, value)
Bundle.putParcelableArrayList(key, value)
Bundle.putStringArrayList(key, value)
```

Most of us are familiar with [item 52 of Effective Java](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/general-programming/ch08lev1sec8) suggesting that objects must be refered to by their interface, so I am wondering what was the reason behind this API decision.

Is `ArrayList` perhaps the preferred list implementation in Android?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just a guess: Maybe Bundele-content must be be serializable and not every Lists implementation is serializable.

From [sdk-doc public Bundle.Bundle (ClassLoader)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#Bundle%28java.lang.ClassLoader%29)

```
  Constructs a new, empty Bundle that uses a specific 
  ClassLoader for instantiating Parcelable and Serializable objects.
```

Comment: makes sense! i'll wait a while more in case someone has a definitive answer.

Comment: the more I go through the tutorial, the more this answer makes sense. so I am accepting it :-)